# JavaScript - прототипно-ориентированный или объектно-ориентированный язык?

Tags: javascript

Зашел я значит на *MDN JavaScript*. Читаю определение и не совсем понимаю, что происходит:

> JavaScript® (часто просто JS) — это легкий, интерпретируемый, **объектно-ориентированный** язык с функциями первого класса.

Понятно. Читаем дальше, тот же абзац:

> JavaScript **прототипно-ориентированный**, мультипарадигменный язык с динамической типизацией, который поддерживает объектно-ориентированный, императивный и декларативный (например, функциональное прогаммирование) стили программирования.

Теперь понятно стало меньше.

Если вести речь о старой спецификации EcmaScript, то там все понятно, слово `class` зарезервировано, но еще не используется. Язык действительно является прототипно-ориентированным. Класса, как понятия, не существует, зато существует объект. Наследование объектов производится через прототипы.

Но тут на сцену выходит EcmaScript 2015, где уже *существует* понятие класса, классы можно наследовать и т.д. и т.п.

Обратимся к Wikipedia:

> **Прототипное** программирование — стиль **объектно-ориентированного** программирования...

То есть получается какая-то несуразица. Зачем MDN пишет, что JS - это прототипно-ориентированный язык, а в дальнейшем еще указывает, что это объектно ориентированный язык, когда можно было просто указать, что это прототипно-ориентированный язык? Ведь прототипно-ориентированный подход является подразделением объектно-ориентированного, насколько я понял, следуя логике Wikipedia.

Прошу помочь разобраться, ведь от этого напрямую должен зависеть стиль кода, который я пишу. Хотя с другой стороны, это же мультипарадигменный язык. Запутался я, короче говоря.

Comment: так в чем вопрос-то заключается? _Прототипное программирование — стиль объектно-ориентированного программирования_ - следовательно _JavaScript - прототипно-ориентированный **и** объектно-ориентированный язык_

Comment: @Grundy вопрос в том, какого стиля кода придерживаться. Вот будет организована полная поддержка ES6, например, и что тогда делать? Как код писать? Продолжать наследовать через прототипы или уже новыми фичами пользоваться?

Comment: ООП это техника. Никаких ОО языков не существует. Просто в одних ООП реализуется легче, чем в других.

Comment: @smellyshovel, учитывая. что классы - это просто надстройка над прототипами, нет никакой разницы как именно писать.

Comment: @Grundy надстройка? Об этом я не знал, и это в корне меняет дело. Ну тогда спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: Классы в JS - синтаксический сахар, по сути. На деле старая, добрая манипуляция с прототипами. См. https://habrahabr.ru/post/131714/

Comment: @Other короче говоря, мы приходим к выводу, что, как ни крути, а JS - прототипно-ориентированный, так?

Comment: Одно не противоречит другому. Тут классы на прототипах. Гибрид, лучшее из обоих направлений, ИМХО.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ООП программировании есть несколько концепций программирования. Среди них находятся класс ориентированное программирование и прототипно ориентированное программирование. 
Между этими стилями программирование есть разница. Но эта разница всего лишь разница в подходе создание объекта - функционал у обеих подходов один и тот же.
В класс ориентированном программирование - создается класс который строго описывает поведение - все экземпляры этого класс будут иметь строго все те свойства что у класса. В прототипно ориентированной среде дело обстоит иначе - здесь объект создается для конкретной цели и в основном он имеет одну реализацию (один экземпляр). Естественно прототип объекта могут наследовать другие классы.

Представь такой пример.
Предположим компания Nissan выпустила машину Skyline все кто видят машину сразу утверждают что дизайнер модели копировал дизайн Infinity Q40 фары, кабина скопированы один в один. В данном случае люди сравнили прототипно - то есть уже есть один прототип который унаследовал другой прототип. 
Это похоже на такой код.

```
var Infinity = {...};
var Skyline = Object.create(Infinity);
```

То есть прототип скопировал (не унаследовал поведение а уже из созданного прототипа скопировал) уже существующий прототип.

В случае с классами дело обстоит иначе.
Класс описывает концепцию, поведение которое получит ее экземпляр. Это можно представить на том же примере. Когда компания представила Skyline все начали  говорить - это есть машина - у нее есть колоса, фары, мотор, кабина. Увидев Infinity люди опять сказали - это машина - у нее есть колоса, фары, мотор, кабина. 
В коде можно описать так.

```
class Car {...};
var Infinity  = new Car();
var Skyline  = new Car();
```

То есть в одном случае прототипы копируют прототипы в другом экземпляры наследуют поведение классов.

Правда это всего лишь концептуально представление этих подходов программирования - по крайне мере обе подхода идентичны по функциональности и возможностям.

Более предметно можешь прочитать [здесь](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/wa-protoop/)

И в вики не плохо [объясняться](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

И [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) можешь обратить внимание на пункт 7

Comment: По делу, исчерпывающе, с примерами. Все как надо и как я люблю. Спасибо!